Can the sandbox concept be improved? Part1: Subforum
Background:
I have recently closely observed the struggle between users that post relevant questions (in their eyes) but the questions are not deemed relevant for the site by "us". Which I find pretentious at best if not downright arrogant towards the users.
A user has a certain concern and seeks help by experts. But instead of helping him to get a step ahead, we always "criticize" the way the question was asked first:

one is "too specific" and declined for being "too plot relevant - will not help"
the other is "too broad" and declined for being "too opinion based - will not help".
Also the trope persists to ask for "how to discern the best answer" because otherwise "will not help"
Leaving little to no room for an "acceptable" question

Asking experts for help: Sheds a bad light upon us, if we send everybody away without actually helping them, although helping with formulating the question is the best help there is.
Sandbox to the rescue! The idea is perfect! I endorse it! But it does not do the trick for me, because it is inconvenient to use and maintain (asking pre-questions as "answer" needing the "comment" functionality for requests/suggestions/improvement tracking - which does not allow bullet-points and has only a letterbox-sized input field, not having the automatic "here is something new" notifications, ...)
Question:
Is it possible to setup a dedicated stack instance like sandbox.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com?

It does not have to be public from the outside.
It can also be exempt from any search engine optimizations.
It is just to provide the same level of convenience in working with "pre-stage" questions as with the "real" questions and their answers.

Best Answer:

Done!
I'm on it.
Yes.
Possibly.

Out of scope:
No.

"not having the automatic "here is something new" notifications," there are notifications for new comments on your answer. If you want notifications for new other answers you can follow the question, or for notification of new comments on other answers, you can follow the answers. Following does notify about (almost) everything, so you'd also get notifications for edits but it does fulfil the notification need. Or did you mean some other kind of notification?

I did mean this kind of notification, but you said it, you will be informed about everything. The sandbox is just "one question"-page therefore, when Following it, I would get notified on any update there, not only on those where I am really involved in. I see this as a major disadvantage. So I would like to have this separated for each pre-staged question. @VLAZ

If you follow a question, you will get notifications for 1. new answers 2. updates to the question. (has to be non-trivial) 3. events that don't happen in the sandbox (close/reopen and comment almost don't happen). You don't get notified for each update to each answer. And 2. happens quite rare, too. There is also an RSS feed for that question (well, every question - it can be found at the end of the right bar) if you prefer that.


Is it possible to setup a dedicated stack instance like sandbox.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com?

I cannot say "no" outright because I am not in any way in a position of authority here. I do not work for SE.
With that said, I have participated on the sites and observed SE. And this is extremely unlikely to ever happen. Sites are made to resemble one another. Each gets a main section and a meta section. Most sites do not even get a chat server1 and things definitely trend towards not diverging the sites.
There are some differences here and there. But they are encoded as site settings that each site can choose to have enabled2 and are way far away from a full on separate section of the site.
With that said, there is maybe something that could come in in the future: the staging ground is an initiative by SE that is modelled after the Sandbox here on WB, as well as a similar kind of sandbox on Puzzling.SE, as well as on Code Golf.SE.
In short, the Staging Ground (SG) aims to be what the sandboxes are but in a more official capacity. New(-ish) users who post a question would automatically end up in SG where reviewers check the question and possibly suggest feedback for how to get it into shape for the main site and publish it when they feel there is nothing else needed. It is a more formal experience than the sandboxes.
Right now, SG is only active on Stack Overflow. SE have had plans when they announced SG to also roll it out to other sites. Presumably using the same toggle as other features, so it can be enabled on a per-site basis.
It does have more to be desired before it can really take over sandboxes. Probably the biggest hurdle I can see right now is that it is not optional. Anybody can post in a sandbox, be they new or veteran user. And yes, even veterans post in the sandbox to workshop their idea before hitting the main site. At the moment, SG does not allow for that.
At any rate, it is not really clear when SG would become an option for other websites. To the best of my knowledge, there is no roadmap or any other rough indication time-wise when it will be available.

1 There are three chat servers in total: 1. Stack Overflow (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ or chat.SO) 2. Meta Stack Exchange (https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ or chat.MSE) 3. all other sites (https://chat.stackexchange.com/ or chat.SE)
2 a recent example is the banner created related to AI generated content which can be enabled on a per-site basis. Here is Worldbuilding's poll for whether to enable it: Do we want to enable a banner stating that AI content is banned on WB.SE?

Awesome information! Thank you! Do you happen to know a timeframe when this SG feature will be rolled out? Can you guesstimate? Or do you have a link at hand to more info? -- I would like to know, if it is useful to further dig into this instead of waiting for the SG, you know

For clarification: Do you mean SG is not open to everyone (on StackOverflow)? Who is able/allowed to post there? "Not optional" seems to imply anyone on SO is forced to post there first... which is a good thing, no?

"Can you guesstimate?" I'm sure it will be ready in 6 to 8. More seriously - I have no good basis for what a reasonable time frame is. Definitely not this year and it might be a stretch even for 2025. SE recently let go a lot of people: 10% back in May 2023 (where 10% is the average, however, engineering teams lost as many as 30% of the people) and another 28% in October 2023. There are less resources.

Optimistically, maybe end about a year from now (Q3-Q4 2024). However, probably 2026 is more realistic. With that said, this is a project SE is working on. I can guess that it will be finished before they release a whole new subdomain for WB (and/or other stacks).

Best guesstimate ever! Thanks again!

"Do you mean SG is not open to everyone (on StackOverflow)? Who is able/allowed to post there?" users over 500 rep can be reviewers in SG. However, once you qualify for a reviewer, you cannot ever post a question in SG. And vice versa - users under 500 rep can only qualify as askers but they cannot review. In theory, all questions from qualifying askers should go through SG. However, in order to not overwhelm reviewers, SE have imposed limits, so only some of the qualifying questions actually go through SG. Nobody can choose whether a question ends up in SG or not.

This is actually very good and I think will be useful sitewide. It would help alleviate some of the workload of our Sandbox, but of course not all of it! Even new users who go through SG might still have to give the SB a go in order to feel competent with how to ask questions here! And as you say, SG isn't intended for general use, and I suspect we would rather not clog that system with WB specific help. So I don't think SG would replace SB.

@elemtilas SG is going to be a per-site thing. And it's a subsection of the main site. In fact, it uses the regular question mechanics (in terms of infrastructure - so you get revisions, timelines, etc. as normal posts). I personally find issues with how SG is currently used but I don't think they have much of an impact away from SO. As I said in my post, the biggest thing I think that needs to be changed for SG to be viable here is to allow anybody to opt into posting questions there. Same applies for Puzzling and Code Golf. I think with that SG can take over the sandbox easily.

@elemtilas for reference, since I think you can't see the Staging Ground on SO here is a screenshot of what a question there looks like - you get the question as normal, with comments under it (they only nest one level, it's not like Reddit or similar). A user leaving a comment can ask for "Major changes" (essentially "can't be published") or "Minor changes" (can be published but some minor polishing is recommended). Or nothing. As a reviewer, there actions available on the top right.

@elemtilas And this is a screenshot of what the question list in SG looks like. To the left is the status - "New" has not been reviewed yet, "re-evaluate" means it was marked as requiring major changes at one point and the author has updated it since. I do think it's a neat system and will be of massive help on SE.

@VLAZ -- I really like how the comments are threaded. That would be super helpful (in my opinion!) sitewide! The actions are a good idea too. Queue looks good too. That is essentially what we try to do in Sandbox, though with all the weird work arounds! Thanks for sharing the screenshots! If all the forums had a SG, we could definitely retire the Sandbox! (Well, not quite, as there's still the issue of allowing access to more experienced users.)


Which I find pretentious at best if not downright arrogant towards the users.

Stack Exchange wrote 90% of the rules. Each Stack develops the other 10%. The rules are stated in the Help Center and discussions have occured about specific issues involving the rules for the last ten years. The only person being arrogant and pretentious is you, thinking that after 37 days (at the time I wrote this answer) you have better insight into this site's Area 51 process, early policy development, and intent than everybody else. There are already sites that allow people to do what they want when they want without regard to structure. You and the other users who don't feel like rules, goals, structure, and expectations should apply to them are welcome to use those services.
And lest we forget, this service is owned by Stack Exchange, Inc. Not you. Not me. Them. As the owners they have the right to define the usage model for the service and you have the right to not use it.

Is it possible to setup a dedicated stack instance like sandbox.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com?

No. While Stack Exchange, Inc. has both the authority and the ability to do this, no user or moderator on Worldbuilding.SE does. You're welcome to visit meta.stackexchange.com and ask for it. That's the appropriate forum to use when asking about how Stack Exchange, Inc. designs its service.
Don't expect much of a response. There's no practical difference between the Sandbox and a Meta-esque subdomain unless you can explain why it makes sense to separate the sandbox function from Meta.
Conclusion
The Sandbox function cannot be improved in this manner.

Gotcha! Thanks.

Some Observations

I think we're on the same page, or at least somewhere in the same book when it comes to watching the struggle that some querents face when trying to ask their questions here. It's not a pretention to insist that queries conform to Stack Exchange's fundamental structures. Nor is it pretentious to insist that queries follow community guidelines, customs, and policies. In an online space that includes Quora, Reddit, and other worldbuilding forums like CBB, the only thing that keeps WB.SE relevant, useful, and needed is the fact that we are part of SE.

You rightly observe that worldbuilders can come here and seek help from a wide variety of experts. Some of these have relevant real world experience with a particular topic, others have relevant worldbuilding experience, while yet others are keen amateurs, renaissance sophonts, and the like.

Part of the duty of a tenured member of any community, whether real life or on line, is to shape up the newbies. They need to learn what the place is for and how the place works. There are a number of ways this could be done. A large cadre of Moderators could simply descend on every question asked and ruthlessly delete or close anything and everything that doesn't fit the culture du jour. That's not how SE works. We do community moderation.

Community moderation is messy. By design. Theoretically everyone in this community has the right to ask a querent for clarification, to VTC, to assist in moderating the forum, and to help in teaching the newbies how the place works and what it's for. Realistically, there's only about a dozen of us who do this regularly. I'm glad you've stepped up!

I do agree that this kind of moderation can come across to a new person as arrogant, unhelpful, unwelcoming, and exclusive. Sometimes we are unwelcoming and exclusive. That's on us. There is plenty of blame to spread to new users as well. Very often they come in here, having never read our Help Center documents, they have no idea what SE is all about, they insist that their incredibly open ended question is perfectly valid and ought to be answered simply because it's them asking. Yes. Querents can be self-centered, vindictive, entitled, unwilling to conform to community norms, and resistant to constructive criticism. I've seen this very recently here.
Possible Solution?

Since we're focused here on the Sandbox, I'll stick to that. Again, I concur that the Sandbox is very helpful. I also agree that it's not very convenient to use! I'm not sure how much of this we can actually change. It seems like question and answer blocks are pretty much the framework of SE. I don't think we're ever going to see anything that breaks this fundamental "look" or aesthetic of SE.

I think we're agreed that the function of the Sandbox is to help querents write better questions. The comments section is therefore very much like comments on Main. "Could you clarify this..." or "Could you format it something like this..." or "Have you considered X..."

Mechanics. I commiserate about the small editing boxes and lack of formatting capabilities there. The only thing I can say there is that you can drag the box taller so you can see the whole comment. As for formatting, I usually end up using bold face numerals to distinguish one point from another. And often make a different comment for each one. Nowhere near perfect! But I'm certain that SE would just say: comments are ephemeral, comments are not for lengthy discussion, comments aren't designed to be formatted, etc. And that's fair. I'd argue that we're probably the only forum that actually needs this kind of nuanced discussion.
The Answer

I have the feeling that SE will not even entertain the idea of essentially giving us three subforums (Main, Meta, Sandbox). This seems to be a deep structure solution that our programmers could better address; but from a moderation and big picture perspective, I really have the feeling this would end up either in the reject pile (because it's only for us) or else in a very low priority pile (if it's proposed sitewide).

I think the only way we would ever see a third subforum is if this were actually proposed as a sitewide modification, something that would be available to every SE forum. I think it would have to be something that is, in some way, clearly announced and made known to all new users especially. Eventually, there would have to be some way of enforcing its use (see entitled querents), Moderators would have to police this across subforums. And most difficult of all, us herd of cats who constitute the majority of community moderators would have to be on board with this.

So! I think a Sandbox subforum is a great idea! My answer, therefore, is are you on it or what!?

Thanks for your reply! The point with the answers/comments mixup is totally valid! I fixed the text. I do know the resizing-feature and I like your workarounds, but still... you know it yourself I am sure, the commenting feature set is inferior. I also can follow your argumentation with the SE/subforum-overhead. As for the "are you on it" - well, I try to be. But I don't know much about the behind-the-scenes stack things.

@Antares -- I'm totally with you on the comment features! By asking if you're on it, I was just simply nudging you in the direction of (not necessarily this instant!) learning some of those behind the scenes things, perhaps getting some discussion going here from those that do, and perhaps eventually actually making this proposal! Also, I edited my response per your comment.
